# Symmetry in triple integral

Tags: integration

in triple integral , when is it valid to use the symmetry , if we have a symmetric solid ?

What I know is that : if we are getting the **volume** of a solid and  the solid is symmetric with respect to x and y and z .. We can make use of symmetry ..

I want to know : if we want the integration of a function (**density** for example) over a symmetric solid (a sphere for example) .. Can we use the symmetry ?

I see that if the solid ,we are integrating over , is symmetric so we can make use of symmetry ..Whether we are getting a mass for example or a volume ..

Can you give me an example in which we can not use the symmetry -due to the function we are integrating - although the solid is symmetric ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider integrating the function

$$
f(x, y, z) = x y^3 z^5
$$

This function has zero symmetry about any axis, since $x$, $y^3$, $z^5$ are all odd functions and have no radial symmetry either.

So, if I ask you to integrate this function over the unit sphere

$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1
$$

You will have to compute the triple integral that corresponds to this since there is no symmetry of the function $f(x, y, z)$ to exploit

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry is useful and simplify the calculus only if there is a common symmetry of the domain of integration and the function that we have to integrate. Otherwise we have to calculate the integral over the entire domain.

As a physical example you can think to the calculus of the mass of a sphere that has a density that is not uniform and not isotropic with respect to the center.